# Django 1.5: When extending base.html, my <head> tag displays in my child's <body>

Tags: django, django-templates

Edit: Adding the full versions of my base and child template.

I'm using Django 1.5.8 and have a base template (in template root) and sub folders for child templates which extend the base.

When I extend base.html all the contents of the base template show up in the body of the child template.  This happens on all child pages except the index.   Is there some Django template inheritance rule that I'm not aware of?

Here is my full base:

```
<!-- base.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% load ganalytics %}
    {% load twitter_tag %}
    {% load compress %}
    {% load tags %}

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">-->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    {% block othermeta %}
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Multimechanics">
    <title>MultiMechanics</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}ico/favicon.ico" />

    <!--Needed for salesforce-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    {% compress css %}
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    {% endcompress %}

    {% ganalytics %}

    {% block otherheader %}{% endblock %}

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo.png" alt="..."></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a href="/logout" class="navbar-btn btn btn-red pull-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">Log Out</a>
                    {% else %}
                    <a href="/login" class="navbar-btn btn btn-red pull-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">Log In</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


                        <li class='dropdown {% active request "^/faqs/$" %} {% active request "^/multiscale/$" %} {% active request "^/about-us/$" %}'>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                {% if request.get_full_path == "/" %}
                                <li><a href="#about">Product Overview</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#features">Product Applications</a></li>
                                {% else %}
                                <li><a href="/">Multimech Home</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                                <li><a href="/about-us">MultiMech Details</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/multiscale">What's Multiscale?</a></li>
                                <!--<li><a href="/porfolio/demos">Demos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/portfolio/case">Case Studies</a></li>-->
                                <li><a href="/faqs">Frequent Questions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class='dropdown {% active request "^/trueinnovation/$" %} {% active request "^/portfolio/$" %}'>
                            <a href="/portfolio" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Showcases <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                {% if request.get_full_path == "/" %}
                                <li><a href="#showcases">Featured Demos</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                                <li><a href="/portfolio">Demo Gallery</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/trueinnovation">Blog</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class='dropdown {% active request "^/careers/$" %} {% active request "^/contact-us/$" %} {% active request "^/login/$" %} {% active request "^/help/$" %} {% active request "^/register/$" %} {% active request "^/thanks/$" %}'>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Connect<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/careers">Careers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/login">User Login</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        {% if request.get_full_path != "/" %}
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="/contact-us">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}


                        <!--     Navbar Search -->
                        <li class="hidden-xs" id="navbar-search">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="hidden" id="navbar-search-box">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>


                    </ul>


                    <!-- Mobile Search -->
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right visible-xs" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-red" type="button">Search!</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- / .navigation -->
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- footer
    ================================================== -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Contact Us -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h4><i class="fa fa-map-marker text-red"></i> Contact Us</h4>
                    <p>Do not hesitate to contact us if you have any questions or feature requests:</p>
                    <p>
                        Omaha, NE 68154<br />
                        14301 FNB Parkway, Suite 100<br />
                        Phone: +1 402 957 1336<br />
                        Email: <a href="mailto:sales@multimechrd.com">sales@multimechrd.com</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- Recent Tweets -->
                {% load twitter_tag cache %}
                {% cache 60 my_tweets %}
                {% get_tweets for "multimechanics" as tweets limit 2 %}

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h4><i class="fa fa-twitter-square text-red"></i> Recent Tweets</h4>
                    {% for tweet in tweets %}
                    <div class="tweet">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
                        <p>
                            {{ tweet.html|safe }}

                        </p>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                </div>

                {% endcache %}
                <!-- Newsletter -->

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h4><i class="fa fa-envelope text-red"></i> Newsletter</h4>
                    <p>
                        Enter your e-mail below to subscribe to our free newsletter.
                        <br>
                        We promise not to bother you often!
                    </p>
                    <!--<form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="/newsletter{{ request.get_full_path }}">-->
                    <form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

                        <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00Di0000000fkHM">
                        <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://multimech2.azurewebsites.net/thanks/newsletter">
                        <input type=hidden name="lead_source" id="lead_source" value="Web">
                        <input type=hidden name="city" id="city" value="{{ip}}">


                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-email">Email address</label>
                                    <!--<input type="email" class="form-control" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="Enter your email">-->
                                    <div class="fieldWrapper">{{ newsletter_form.email }}</div>
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="newsletter_form">OK</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="copyright">
                    Copyright 2014 - MultiMechanics, LLC | All Rights Reserved
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  <!-- / .row -->
    </div> <!-- / .container -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    {% compress js %}

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/scrolltopcontrol.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/custom.js"></script>

    {% endcompress %}

    {% block otherfooter %}{% endblock %}


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my full child:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}
    <!-- Wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">

      <!-- Topic Header -->
      <div class="topic">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <h3>Sign In</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <ol class="breadcrumb pull-right hidden-xs">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active">Log In</li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="sign-form">
              <div class="sign-inner">
                <h3 class="first-child">Log In To Your Account</h3>
                <hr>
                  <form role="form" action="" method="post">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>

                          {{form.username}}

                      </div>
                      <br>
                      <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>

                          {{form.password}}

                      </div>
                      <div class="checkbox">
                          <!--<label>
                              <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                          </label>-->
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-red" name="login_form">Submit</button>
                      <hr>
                  </form>
                <p>Not registered? <a href="/register">Create an Account.</a></p>
                <div class="pwd-lost">
                  <div class="pwd-lost-q show">Lost your password? <a href="#">Click here to recover.</a></div>
                    <!--https://github.com/brutasse/django-password-reset-->

                  <div class="pwd-lost-f hidden">
                    <p class="text-muted">Enter your email address below and we will send you a link to reset your password.</p>
                    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="email-pwd">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-pwd" placeholder="Enter email">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue">Send</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- / .pwd-lost -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- / .row -->      
      </div> <!-- / .container -->

    </div> <!-- / .wrapper -->

  {% endblock %}
```

Here is how the html is rendered:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body style="">
    <!-- base.html -->
    <!--[if lt IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gte IE 8)|!(IE)]><!-->
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">-->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/static/img/logo.png" alt="..."></a>
                </div>
                <div c
```

Here is how I render that page (but I use "render_to_response" for other templates and get the same result:

```
url(r'^about-us/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about-us.html"), name='about-us'),
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Looks like you might be including `base.html` instead of extending it.

Comment: Thought about that, but no. I'm definitely using extends.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem.

Changing encoding of my files to "**utf-8 without BOM**" solved my issue.

(http://validator.w3.org/ may help u.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're editing the correct "base.html" file? It appears that you may be editing a file that has the same name, but is in a different location. Also, are you using Javascript or something to populate your `<navigation> </navigation>` ? The rendered result does not match your base.html. If you are generating this navigation section using Javascript, this could be your culprit. If it was redacted for readability, then I would search for another instance of "base.html" or "about-us.html" in your project folder. You may find that you are editing the wrong file. Can you post the complete files "base.html" and "about-us.html" and the entire response?

Edit: I believe the issue may be in your "othermeta" block. You can see that the following lines render correctly:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">-->

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is the point in your result that gets messy. It is also the point in your base when you call for `{% block othermeta %}`. Is there a reason you have that block with content inside? I'm not sure it is accepting the {% endblock %} correctly. If you want the block `othermeta` to be dynamic, you must have it in its own `othermeta.html`, which extends `base.html` as well. Then, you would change your code to simply:

```
{% block othermeta %} {% endblock %}
```

I think the error may be that you're trying to define the contents of this block in an extended template. I'm new at this like you, so I could be completely wrong, but try removing your `othermeta` block entirely for now and see if it helps.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry - those were redacted versions.  No fancy JS being used to generate the nav.  The strange thing is that my Index.html gets rendered properly but all other pages in the site do not.

Comment: Thanks for posting more information! I've edited my answer. Any luck?

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. I ended up just doing some hackey hardcoding for now until I can come back and investigate.

Answer (score 0):

After having the same issue in 2019, this was, as Majid Mobini said, due to the encoding of the source files by Visual Studio. As VS 2019 no longer has the Advanced Save options, my solution was to install the Fix File Encoding extension from the VS Marketplace and resave my files - which then placed the meta in the HEAD as expected.